# Azure microservices for message transaction

Tags: json, azure, azure-function-app-proxy

I want to achieve microservices architecture. I've converted my XML message into json. I am going to split the message based on micro services and each microservices will deserialize few json content and store few fields in a object. Then I am going to group all objects from various microservices again in a single object to move for further process.

How to achieve this? i just want to do it with function app.

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to Azure Service Bus(es) and Web Jobs (under web apps). Unprocessed JSON or XML could exist as messages in a particular queue. You can then use continual web jobs (under Azure Web Apps) to monitor the bus. Use C# in a Web Job to monitor and then parse your message as needed, and then put the results into another bus (or one bus with multiple queues). Another web job can process that bus. Etc., etc...

In this model, you can stitch together a nice SOA workflow.

Good luck, Dhivakar!